# Python will not understand List

Tags: python, list, sorting, duplicates

Sorry I have a very basic python question. In the following program I'm trying to duplicate a list and then sort it in ascending order. The code I've written is:

```
def lesser_than(thelist):

    duplicate = thelist[:]
    duplicate = duplicate.sort()
    return duplicate
```

The error it gives me is that it cannot sort something of the type None. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 5):

`list.sort` sorts the list in place and returns `None`.  This is a common python convention -- If the operation is in-place, python *usually* returns `None`.  So, your code should be:

```
duplicate = thelist[:]
duplicate.sort()  # Note, no assignment
return duplicate
```

Alternatively, you could use `sorted`:

```
return sorted(thelist)
```

Since `sorted` already returns a sorted copy, you should be all good (with the side benefit of supporting arbitrary iterables rather than simply lists...)

<sup>Note that there is a slight naming convention at play here.  verbs like `sort`, `reverse` generally operate in-place when it makes sense for them to do so -- verbs like `sorted` or `reversed` make copies.  I wouldn't say that this convention is ubiquitous, but it does exist at least with the builtins...</sup>

Comment: @mhawke -- That's actually a little tidbit that I just had pointed out to me recently.  It's interesting ... I hadn't noticed it before.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that `sort()` *sorts* the list **in-place**, so it doesn't return a new list.

*What can you do?*

- You can use `sorted()`, which returns a sorted list:

  ```
  duplicate = sorted(duplicate)
  ```
- Or, you can just make the operation (`duplicate.sort()`) and return the sorted list:

  ```
  duplicate = thelist[:]
  duplicate.sort()
  return duplicate
  ```